# Select based on csv file values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to take a csv file with numerous values and feed these values into a postgres select statement. For example if i had a csv file called text.csv with values 1,2,3,4,5,6... is there a way for me to perform a select such as:

```
select * 
from table 
where id in (test.csv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fdw-file - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html - foreign data wrapper which allows you to use file as table.

Here is example - http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/250-File-FDW-Family-Part-1-file_fdw.html

Comment: See in example - (after you create "foreign server" etc. as described) you will create so called "foreign table" and this table will behave as normal table in select. But data will be taken from file.

Answer (score -1):

Well this is how it can be done !

```
Select * from table where id in (
  select id from openrowset('MSDASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from c:\test.csv')
  )
```

In case if your sql server is not enabled for Ad Hoc Distributed Queries, fire below sql first.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Good Luck !
Keyur

Comment: That is invalid SQL and invalid for Postgres as well (the only two tags on the question)